# Difference between min/max-entropies and the von Neumann entropy

Tags: entropy, max-entropy, min-entropy

Consider the (smooth) min-entropy, max-entropy and von Neumann entropy of a given density operator $\rho_A$. Does a small gap between $H_{\max(\min)}(A)_\rho$ and $H(A)_\rho$ implies a small gap between  $H_{\min(\max)}(A)_\rho$ and $H(A)_\rho$? Put in other words, does a small gap between the von Neumann entropy and either min- or max-entropy implies a nearly flat spectrum of $\rho_A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly with "small gap", but you can easily build examples where $H(A)$ and $H_{\rm max}(A)$ are "maximally different". For example,
$$\rho = \begin{pmatrix}1-\epsilon & 0 \\ 0 &\epsilon\end{pmatrix}$$
for small $\epsilon>0$, has $H(\rho)\simeq 0$, but $H_{\rm max}(\rho)=\log|\operatorname{supp}(\rho)|=1$. You can build similar examples in any dimension.
In these cases $H(\rho)\simeq H_{\rm min}(\rho)$ but $H_{\rm max}(\rho)$ is rather different.

On the other hand, to have $H(\rho)\simeq H_{\rm max}(\rho)$ it seems you'd need a more or less balanced nonzero eigenvalues, which would then also make $H_{\rm min}(\rho)\simeq H(\rho)$.

Here's a plot of the three quantities for the possible distributions over two outcomes:

[image]

We can also do the same for three-outcome distributions, obtaining essentially the same result:

[image]

This is, however, significantly harder to parse without being able to rotate the figure. One way to see that the relations between $H,H_{\rm min},H_{\rm max}$ we had before remains here, is to show only the difference between $H$ and $H_{\rm min}$:

[image]

This clearly shows that $H\simeq H_{\rm max}$ whenever we have a balanced distribution, be it $P\simeq (1/3,1/3,1/3)$, or things like $P\simeq (1/2,1/2,0)$. But nearby this point, we also have $H\simeq H_{\rm min}$.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I mean by gap. I see your point.  It seems a bit strange to me that there's this asymmetry between them.

Comment: There's no asymmetry, it is possible to also make Hmin and H arbitrarily far apart whilst Hmax and H are close. The comment on this in the answer is a little misleading.

Comment: @Rammus I suppose you mean with distributions with more outcomes? It doesn't seem like it's possible for distributions with few outcomes. I guess you'd need a mostly balanced distribution over many outcomes, with a single outcome associated with a much larger probability? Do you have an explicit example?

Comment: Yes, you need more outcomes to amplify the gap, but the example is exactly what you say. Large probability on one and flat on the rest. I think I wrote it out explicitly on a recent question of yours but I can't check right now.

Comment: @Rammus if you're referring to the example in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/28068/55), that is, essentially, $p_k=\delta/N$ for $k=1,...,N$ and $p_0=1-\delta$, then we have there $H(p)=H(\delta) + \delta \log N$, $H_{\rm max}(p)=\log_2 (N+1)$, and $H_{\rm min}(p)=\log(1/(1-\delta))$. So $H_{\rm min}\sim 0$, $H_{\rm max}\sim \log N$, and $H\sim \delta \log N$. I don't know that I'd say that in this examples $H$ is "close" to $H_{\rm max}$. They both increase with $\log N$, but they remain quite distant, especially for small $\delta$

Comment: Yes they cant be made arbitrarily close with that example but if you take $\delta=1/2$ then they grow with only a factor $1/2$ difference whilst Hmin remains at 1.

Comment: @Rammus well, then my point stands. Is there any example of a state/probability distributions with $H\simeq H_{\rm max}$ (as in, say, they're $\epsilon$-close for some small $\epsilon$) , and $H-H_{\rm min}$ larger than some constant? Because I'm struggling to imagine how you could have $H\simeq H_{\rm max}$ without the distribution being close to fully balanced. A single much larger probability would be sufficient to significantly affect this and make $H$ depart from $H_{\rm max}$

Comment: @Rammus  I think I agree glS that it's hard to separate $H$ and $H_\min$ without also separating $H$ and $H_\max$, but this is okay the other way around, and hence the asymmetry. The example you mentioned above doesn't seem to work. Do you have another example to support your claim?

Comment: @Shadumu in what way are you saying it "doesn't work"? It shows that at least in small dimensions there is this "asymmetry". It's not a proof for the general case, but no example will give you that anyway. It's also very much a matter of how you define "close", in what limit you consider it, etc. In Rammus' example you have that, for large $N$, $H_{\rm min}\sim0$ while $H$ and $H_{\rm max}$ both grow as $\log N$, albeit with different multiplicative factors. Whether that's an example of "$H$ and $H_{\rm max}$ being close but different from $H$" depends on what you mean

Comment: @glS  I mean it as how you described in your previous comment. Say one can set the gap between $H$ and $H_\max$ arbitrarily small without also shrinking the gap between $H$ and $H_\max$. As you said, it's hard to imagine how this would work. The given example does't work in the sense that both gaps grow as $\log N$.